# Name of this topological property of manifolds (and intrinsic geometry of curves)

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, curves

It's well known that there is no intrinsic geometry of curves and that the only connected $1$-manifolds are $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{S}^1$. In other words $R \equiv 0$ (the curvature tensor) for any $1$-dimensional smooth manifold. I've been thinking about this and naturally I've come to the conclusion that if I were a point on the circle and my friend was a point on the real line, we'd have no way to tell where we are (not without leaving our worlds and talking about ambient spaces) by any geometrical properties: that is, there is no geometrical intrinsic property from $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{S}^1$ that can distinguish between them. This is kind of intuitive: no matter how I smoothly deform a rope, the distance of points on the rope will always remain the same (I think this means any diffeomorphism between two $1$-dimensional Riemannian manifolds must be an isometry - is that right?).

But there is one obvious experiment that an inhabitant of the circle could perform to conclude they're not in the real line: if they start walking forward, they're eventually gonna come back to the same place they started the walk. This obviously doesn't happen on the real line. So this must be a topological property. What is it? I think it must have something to do with the fundamental group, because it's obviously not compactness, connectedness or anything I can tell straight away. So what's the name for this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One property *is* compactness! The circle is compact but the real line is not.
2. The one you’re thinking of, though, is that the real line is simply-connected but the circle is not.
3. It’s *not* true that every map between one-manifolds is an isometry. Just take for instance $f(x)=2x$ which maps the real line to itself but clearly distorts distances.

Comment: Simple connectedness, that was the one! Thanks. About 3, I don't know how I could be so foolish, it's obviously not true. I didn't think compactness had anything to do with it but of course it does. Thanks.